# How many elements are there in the vector space over F of dimension 5

Tags: vector-spaces

When $F = \mathbb  Z_2$ (the two element field), how many elements are there in the vector space over $F$ of dimension $5$?

Would it be $32$?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Use the fact that for a basis, every vector has a unique expression as alinear combination of basis vectors; and then you can count for any field of arbitrary number of elements.

Comment: So it couldn't be 32. There are only as many elements in the vector space as there are in the basis?

Comment: Yes, $32$ is correct.

Comment: No.  In case of 2 vectors $u,v$ in the basis the set of linear combinations are $ 0.u + 1.v = v;\quad 1.u +0.v= u;\quad 1.u + 1.v = u+v;\quad 0.u + 0. v = 0$. Now you can work out for the 5 dimensional case.

Comment: There can be many more elements in the space than there are basis vectors. Your guess of $32=2^5$ is correct. In general an $m$-dimensional vector space over a field with $q$ elements will have $q^m$ vectors. You can prove this by using @PVanchinathan's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are as many elements in the vector space as there are *linear combinations* of the basis vectors. Alternatively, every vector is of the form $(a, b, d, c, e)$, where each of $a, b, c, d, e$ are either $0$ or $1$. So $32$ is correct.